# Eilenberg-Zilber Proof

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently reading the book "Algebraic Topology" by Tammo Tom Dieck: [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf)

I don't understand the proof he gives of the theorem of Eilenberg-Zilber. He wants to use the acyclic model theorem:
[image]

and he proves that the functors $S_{\bullet}(-) \otimes S_{\bullet}(-) $ and $S_{\bullet}(-\times-) $ are both free and acyclic.
He then defines the Eilenberg-Zilber morphisms as $P:S_0(X)\otimes S_0(Y) \to S_0(X\times Y)$ such that $x \otimes y \mapsto (x, y)$ and $Q:S_0(X\times Y) \to S_0(X)\otimes S_0(Y)$ such that $(x,y) \mapsto x \otimes y$.

In order to conclude we should prove that $P$ and $Q$ induce natural transformation on the zeroth homology group so that we can apply the acyclic model theorem and extend $P$ and $Q$ to their chain complexes. Their composition is homotopic to the identity using again the acyclic model theorem.

The problem is that the map $P:S_0(X)\otimes S_0(Y) \to S_0(X\times Y)$ doesn't seem to induce a well defined map  $\bar{P}:H_0(X\otimes Y) \to H_0(X\times Y)$. In fact let $a \in S_1(X)$ and $b \in S_0(Y)\setminus Im(\partial_1^Y)$, then $\partial_1^X(a)\otimes b \in Im(\partial_1^{X\otimes Y})$ because $\partial_1^X(a)\otimes b=\partial_1^{X\otimes Y}(a\otimes b)$, on the other hand $(\partial_1^X(a),b) \notin Im(\partial_1^{X\times Y}) $ because i chose $b \notin Im(\partial_1^Y)$.

What is the problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For every continuous map $a:\Delta_1\to X$ and every $b\in Y,$
$$(\partial_1^X(a),b)=(a(1),b)-(a(0),b)=(a,b)(1)-(a,b)(0)=\partial_1^{X\times Y}(a,b).$$

Comment: I thought that $\partial_1^{X \times Y}(a,b) =(\partial_1^X(a),\partial_1^Y(b))$, but this is incompatible with what you wrote. What is the definition of $\partial_1^{X\times Y}$ you are using?

Comment: Are you the downvoter? $\partial_1^Y(b)$ has no meaning for an element $b\in Y.$ The definition of $\partial_1^Z(c)$ for any continuous map $c:\Delta_1\to Z$ is $\partial_1^Z(c)=c(1)-c(0).$ It applies here to $c=(a,b):\Delta_1\to Z=X\times Y,\;t\mapsto(a(t),b).$